# Change button data-tooltip text using Jquery Ajax (Received from

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my HTML code

```
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="ADD TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>

   // Same form as above
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="ADD TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); 
        $(form).children("button").data('tooltip', data.addremove + " TO YOUR WATCHLIST"); // This line not working
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
</script>
```

PHP file `insertwatchlist.php` file

```
$response = new \stdClass();
$response->addremove = "REMOVE";//you can get the data anyway you want(e.g database)
$response->watchlisticoncolor = "red";
die(json_encode($response));
```

Output of PHP file `insertwatchlist.php` file

```
{"addremove":"REMOVE","watchlisticoncolor":"red"}
```

**Expected Result:**

1.)When someone clicks on add_box button, it submits the form without reloading the page (This one works fine)

2.) When someone clicks on `add_box` button, it's `color` changes. (works fine too)

3.) When someone click on `add_box` button, the `data-tooltip=""` value changes. (this one do not work)

So the 3rd point do not work as expected, what is wrong in my Jquery code? Console tab is empty, it shows nothing.

Comment: try `$(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip', data.addremove + " TO YOUR WATCHLIST");`

Comment: Are you sure it isn't working? Did you try alerting `$(form).children("button").data("tooltip");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jquery code should be like this

```
$(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + "TO YOUR WATCHLIST");
```

or

```
$('.material-icons').attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + "TO YOUR WATCHLIST");
```

Comment: Please don't tell someone it "should" be something when in fact his code is perfectly valid: https://api.jquery.com/data/ - Most likely he's checking the source code of his page to see if the value changed there, which (afaik) doesn't happen.

Comment: ok i understand i should have wriiten 'jquery code couldbe like this'

Comment: So just edit your answer. Try explaining why you think that jQuery code will work while his doesn't. That way future readers can learn from your experience. And you'll definitely get a +1 from me for it :)